# How to append to each record in the json file without using for loops in python?

Tags: python, json

How to change the following dictionary

```
{ "records": 
  [ 
    { "value": {"col1":"val11","col2":"val12"} }, 
    { "value": {"col1":"val21","col2":"val22"} } 
  ] 
}
```

to this

```
{ "records": 
  [ 
    {  "key": "key-1",
       "value": {"col1":"val11","col2":"val12"} 
    }, 
    { "key": "key-2",
      "value": {"col1":"val21","col2":"val22"} 
    } 
  ] 
}
```

possibly **avoiding for loops**. The problem is, that in my case these jsons can get very large, with millions of such entries. A for loop will be a performance killer in this case.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried with for loop to make this statement ? Using for loop what do you measure in term of performances for your dataset ?

Comment: I would add on to Ant0ine64's question the question of how large these datasets you're working with can get (in terms of MB or GB or larger) - knowing that might also help understand whether data manipulation in Python is the appropriate tool, versus a database of some kind (such as MongoDb)

Comment: What on earth makes you say "A for loop will be a performance killer in this case."?

Comment: "Millions" of entries in a JSON? Seriously? If so, you're not using the right tool(s)

Comment: I am not claiming any expertise. If you can advise me any good tool - I would be very happy. I am just limited by some business applications we have, which also run on quite strange servers.

It might be hundreds of megabytes of pure data, which then multiply in the RAM here and there to tens of gigabytes. I have to research more on the server which is running the application, but the application wants only python scripts and gets overwhealmed very fast. That is why we try to use vectorization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is version without *explicit* loop (but I'd recommend to use normal for-loop for readability, the performance will be +/- the same):

```py
dct = {
    "records": [
        {"value": {"col1": "val11", "col2": "val12"}},
        {"value": {"col1": "val21", "col2": "val22"}},
    ]
}

dct["records"] = list(
    map(
        lambda r: {
            "key": f"key-{r[0]}",
            "value": r[1]["value"],
        },
        enumerate(dct["records"], 1),
    )
)

print(dct)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "records": [
        {"key": "key-1", "value": {"col1": "val11", "col2": "val12"}},
        {"key": "key-2", "value": {"col1": "val21", "col2": "val22"}},
    ]
}
```